# Trying to fetch data from the request body

Tags: jmeter

I am making a post call to the following URL with the payload, I want to fetch the value `new_name` and `mib_title`. Through the post processer

POST https://api.dev.net/api/data/v9.0/new_studies

```
POST data:
{"new_readenddate":"2022-08-04T08:03:08.26Z","new_studystatus":100000001,"new_serviceenddate":"2022-08-24T08:03:08.26Z","new_phase":100000000,"new_SponsorOrganization@odata.bind":"/cr420_sponsors(0d8ab049-eb08-ed11-82e4-002248093996)","new_SponsorOrganization@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"0VFRwqrK","cr420_contractvalue":22424,"new_readstartdate":"2022-08-04T08:03:08.26Z","new_servicestartdate":"2022-07-31T08:03:08.26Z","new_studystate":100000000,"new_globalstudyid":"2224","mib_title":"PERF2VxlO3BPI","new_name":"PERF6TruGhT8M","mib_isretry":false,"mib_flowstate":913380000,"statuscode":1,"statecode":0,"ownerid@odata.bind":"/systemusers(6d94fcb3-32e2-ec11-bb3d-000d3a3437fc)","ownerid@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"PerformanceExecuter"}
Cookie Data:
ReqClientId=24552c6c-7e0b-43cb-b59e-953a77233416;
```

Have added a post processer to retrieve a JSR223 post processer with the following code,

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def requestPayLoad = "";
sampler.getArguments().each {arg ->
    requestPayLoad = arg.getStringValue()   
}
def removedSymbolPayload = requestPayLoad.replace('=', '');
removedSymbolPayload.each { getKeyValue ->
     log.info("Key = " + getKeyValue)
    }
```

And I am getting the response as,

```
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = {
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = "
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = n
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = e
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = w
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = _
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = r
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = e
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = a
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = d
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = e
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = n
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = d
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = d
2022-08-02 20:03:08,899 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = a
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = t
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = e
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = "
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = :
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = "
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 2
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 0
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 2
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 2
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = -
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 0
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 8
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = -
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 0
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 4
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = T
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 0
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 8
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = :
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 0
2022-08-02 20:03:08,900 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Key = 3(contd..)
```

What I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to fetch data from the **request**? It's **you** who sends the request, you should know the values of the attributes beforehand, if you don't - it means that your test is badly designed.

Whatever

The code you're looking for is something like:

```
def body = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())

def new_name = body.new_name
def mib_title = body.mib_title

log.info('new_name=' + new_name)
log.info('mib_title=' + mib_title)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, yeah I know but we need that value. This worked fine thank you so much.